# pandas: convert index type in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, types, multi-index

Hi have a multiindex dataframe:

```
tuples = [('YTA_Q3', 1), ('YTA_Q3', 2), ('YTA_Q3', 3), ('YTA_Q3', 4), ('YTA_Q3', 99), ('YTA_Q3', 96)]
# Index
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Questions', 'Values'])
# Columns
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('YTA_Q3', '@')], names=['Questions', 'Values'])
# Data
data = [29.014949,5.0260590000000001,
  6.6269119999999999,
  1.3565260000000001,
  41.632221999999999,
  21.279499999999999]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

How do I convert the inner values of the df's index to str?

My attempt:

```
df1.index.astype(str)
```

returns a TypeError

Answer (score 40, accepted):

IIUC you need the last level of Multiindex. You could access it with `levels`:

```
df1.index.levels[-1].astype(str)

In [584]: df1.index.levels[-1].astype(str)
Out[584]: Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '96', '99'], dtype='object', name='Values')
```

**EDIT**

You could set your inner level with `set_levels` method of multiIndex:

```
idx = df1.index
df1.index = df1.index.set_levels([idx.levels[:-1], idx.levels[-1].astype(str)])
```

Comment: this is good, but how do i update my df1 ? df1.index.levels[1] = df.index.levels[1].astype(str)

Comment: why not do reset index and then set index? [real question!]

Comment: Your EDIT for updating does not work, saying 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'levels' ?

Comment: @Rockbar `id` is the same as `df1.index`. Edited for that

Comment: Could it be that the edit should be `df1.index = df1.index.set_levels(idx.levels[:-1] + [idx.levels[-1].astype(str),])` to allow for more than two levels of indexing?

Comment: 'set_levels' can also be run `inplace=True` to avoid having to set it back to itself.

Comment: For multiple levels, you can do: `df1.index = df1.index.set_levels(idx.levels[-1].astype(int), level=-1)`

Comment: Note that both `levels` and `astype(str)` will sort the individual levels *lexicographically*. This may reorder the index labels for a given level without maintaining the MultiIndex tuples (e.g., if you have indices 1-100, these will be reordered as 1,10,100,2,20,3..., independently of other levels).

Answer (score 18):

There was change in pandas and old way doesn't work properly.

For me this worked.

```
level_to_change = 1
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[level_to_change].astype(int), level=level_to_change)
```

Comment: Worked swellingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Only specific types seem to be supported, like `'int64'`, `'float64'`, `'object'` (for strings) and probably date time related, but not something like `'int16'` or `'float32'`. Try it with: `df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0].astype('float32'), level=0).dtypes`

Answer (score 3):

I find the current pandas implementation a bit cumbersome, so I use this:

`df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(ix[0], str(ix[1])) for ix in df1.index.tolist()])`

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the party, but if you also want to maintain the names on your multi-index levels, I'd suggest the following:

```
df_ts.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    pd.DataFrame(index=df_ts.index)
    .reset_index().astype(int)
    )
```

Similarly if you have multi-index columns, you can use:

```
df_ts.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
        pd.DataFrame(index=df_ts.columns)
        .reset_index().astype(int)
        )
```

Comment: Only solution that work for me, great

Comment: This only works if all the levels can be converted to `int`.

Comment: Works well when you want to convert all to str for multiindex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not that elegant as last solution though it will set column names dtype to str for all multi-index levels (when df.columns is a multi-index):

```
df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(i).astype(str) for i in range(len(df.columns.levels)
```

Hope this helps too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to set **any combination of dtypes** for **any number of index levels**, in a **name-based way,** is the following

```
# define your desired target index schema as a dict (name, and dtype), allowing any number of columns and dtypes
my_index_schema: Dict[str, str] = {'country': 'str', 'indep_day': 'datetime64[ns]', 'population': 'int'}

# get the MultiIndex of the current df, make it a frame, and set the desired dtypes
new_index_frame = df.index.to_frame().astype(my_index_schema)

# overwrite the current index of df by the new index (converted to MultiIndex)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(new_index_frame)
```

The shortcoming of all other answers here is that they are either "level-number"-based (so you have to hope that the index level that you want to set to "dtype" happens to be at the hard-coded position X, say "3"), or that they are setting the same dtype for all index levels. The above dict-based version overcomes both.