# Change Pandas index datatype on MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have a Pandas dataframe with two indexes

```
                              Column1
indexA   indexB                        
1001     aaa                        1
         bbb                        1
         ccc                        1
         ddd                        1
```

created by

```
pd.read_sql(sql=sql, index_col=['indexA', 'indexB'])
```

MySQL is reading in `indexB` as unicode and I would like to convert it to a string. My goal is to pivot the table and have the entries in `indexB` be the column names. When I do this with the unicode values I get the following column names:

```
�  �  �  �  �  �  �  �  �
```

when running

```
pd.read_sql(sql=sql, index_col=['indexA', 'indexB']).unstack().fillna(0)
```

**EDIT:** A comment suggested the following:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql)
df['indexB'] = df['indexB'].astype(str)
df = df.set_index(('indexA', 'indexB'), drop=True)
```

which is a nice work around to my problem (thank you). Would still be nice to know if this can be done during initialization.

Comment: Have you tried `df['indexB'] = df['indexB'].astype(str)`?

Comment: I don't think you can access indices like that. The above returns `KeyError: 'indexB'`

Comment: Right, sorry, you would need `df = pd.read_sql(sql); df['indexB'] = df['indexB'].astype(str); df = df.set_index(('indexA', 'indexB'), drop=True))`

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Was hoping to do everything on initialization. Your answer gives me some new errors (added above).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: convert index type in multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417970/pandas-convert-index-type-in-multiindex-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

the index can be reset before changing the type.

```
df= df.reset_index()
df['indexB'] = df['indexB'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If df.columns is a MultiIndex and if you want to change all column names for multiple levels at once:

Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128216/11541027