# Pandas cast all levels of a multi-index to another type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a multi-index and I would like to convert all of its levels to float.

I'm doing the following:

```
        my_dataframe.index.map(lambda i: (float(i[0]), float(i[1])))
```

However this does not seem to "scale" very well if I have many levels.

I tried this:

```
        my_dataframe.index.astype(np.float, copy=False)
```

but it fails with a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: Setting <class 'pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex'> dtype to anything other than object is not supported
```

What would be the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: provide sample of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for select levels, convert to `float`s and last :

```
a = my_dataframe.index.get_level_values(0).astype(float)
b = my_dataframe.index.get_level_values(1).astype(float)

my_dataframe.index = [a,b]
```

Or:

```
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.set_index([a,b])
```

Another solution with [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
a = my_dataframe.index.levels[0].astype(float)
b = my_dataframe.index.levels[1].astype(float)
my_dataframe.index = my_dataframe.index.set_levels([a,b])
```

Or:

```
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.set_index(my_dataframe.index.set_levels([a,b]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about `get_level_values` :)

Comment: For `.levels()`, there is a worning "TypeError: 'FrozenList' object is not callable". I wonder why? `my_dataframe.columns.levels(0).astype(str)`

Comment: @Sean.H - how working `[]` instead `my_dataframe.columns.levels[0].astype(str)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Oh~ my fault. Of course `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you df.columns is a MultiIndex and you want to cast all levels of a multi-index column names to another type, say int to str, then you might find this useful:

```
pivot_2d.columns = [pivot_2d.columns.get_level_values(i).astype(str) for i in range(len(pivot_2d.columns.levels)
```

or even better:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns).reset_index().astype(int))
```

Good luck!