# How to preserve category dtype in pandas multiindex when concatenating data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, multi-index, categorical-data

I'm handling data (in my real use case, chromosome names, but here I used dummy names) for which I want to be able to control the sort order, and that will be part of a `MultiIndex` (also containing positions within chromosomes: I want to sort my data by chromosome, then position).

To ensure the desired sort order, it seems possible to have a `Categorical` in the index.
However, the dtype is lost from the `MultiIndex` once I concatenate dataframes.

(In the following example, "A" plays the role of my chromosome information, and "B" plays the role of the positional information. "C" is some unique locus identifier.)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": pd.Categorical(
        ["X9", "X9", "X10", "X10"],
        categories=["X8", "X9", "X10"], ordered=True),
    "B": [1, 2, 1, 2],
    "C": ["9_1", "9_2", "10_1", "10_2"],
    "1": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
).set_index(["A", "B", "C"])
print(df1.index.dtypes)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": pd.Categorical(
        ["X8", "X8", "X10", "X10"],
        categories=["X8", "X9", "X10"], ordered=True),
    "B": [1, 2, 1, 2],
    "C": ["8_1", "8_2", "10_1", "10_2"],
    "2": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
).set_index(["A", "B", "C"])
print(df2.index.dtypes)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index()
print(df.index.dtypes)
print(df.to_string())
```

The above code generates the following output:

```
A    category
B       int64
C      object
dtype: object
A    category
B       int64
C      object
dtype: object
A    object
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
              1    2
A   B C             
X10 1 10_1  3.0  3.0
    2 10_2  4.0  4.0
X8  1 8_1   NaN  1.0
    2 8_2   NaN  2.0
X9  1 9_1   1.0  NaN
    2 9_2   2.0  NaN
```

We can see that the index-sorted concatenated dataframe is sorted alphabetically on level "A", which is coherent with the fact that the dtype is not categorical any more, but I want "8" and "9" to come before "10", and I can't just drop the "X" and convert these names to ints (remember that these are supposed to be chromosome names, where, in the case of humans, we can have chromosomes "X" and "Y").

How can I preserve the index dtypes when concatenating?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463725/1878788, I was able to restore the desired dtypes in the concatenated dataframe, as follows:

```
df = df.set_index(df.index.set_levels(
    df.index.levels[0].astype(
        pd.CategoricalDtype(
            ["X8", "X9", "X10"],
            ordered=True)),
    level=0)).sort_index()
print(df.index.dtypes)
print(df.to_string())
```

This results in the following output:

```
A    category
B       int64
C      object
dtype: object
              1    2
A   B C             
X8  1 8_1   NaN  1.0
    2 8_2   NaN  2.0
X9  1 9_1   1.0  NaN
    2 9_2   2.0  NaN
X10 1 10_1  3.0  3.0
    2 10_2  4.0  4.0
```

That said, it would be nice if there was a way to avoid loosing the dtypes in the first place.