# Change the type of a column multi-index level?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multi-index

I am reading a `.csv` file that looks like this:

```
,1,1,2,2,3,3...
,'A','B','A','B',...
0,1,2,3,4,...
1,2,3,4,5,...
```

I read this with
`df = pd.read_csv(fname,header=[0,1],index_col=0)`

Now, deplorably, pandas sets the dtype of the first level of the column multiindex to string, even though there are only integers in the first row of the file. Unfortunately, there is no way to tell pandas what dtype to use for each row (level) of the column index. (Something like `header={0:'int64',1:'string'}`).

Now, it seems that there should be a simple and easy way to convert one level of the multiindex columns to `int`, but I searched for a long time and could not come up with anything. Right now, I am re-generating the index from scratch, but that seems overkill.

Another solution that could possibly work would be to convert the multiindex to a DataFrame, change the dtypes, then set the index from the DataFramce. That also seems like an overcomplicated process.

Suggestions?

Comment: There is a [PR](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/pull/1317) in [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to do this. Just rip the code and use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418099/7175713 is also another option

Comment: could also use `df.rename(int,level=0,axis=1)`

Comment: @rhug123: This really works. Congratulations for the shortest answer. It isn't evident from the rename documentation.

Comment: One additional advantage of @rhug123's solution is that it does not mess up the order of the labels. In other words, the labels are sorted numerically instead of lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
csvstr = '''
,1,1,2,2,3,3
,'A','B','A','B','A','B'
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvstr),header=[0,1],index_col=0)

df.columns.dtypes
# level_0    object
# level_1    object
# dtype: object

df.columns
# MultiIndex([('1', ''A''),
#             ('1', ''B''),
#             ('2', ''A''),
#             ('2', ''B''),
#             ('3', ''A''),
#             ('3', ''B'')],
#            )

df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.levels[0].astype('int64'), level=0)

df.columns.dtypes
# level_0     int64
# level_1    object
# dtype: object

df.columns
# MultiIndex([(1, ''A''),
#             (1, ''B''),
#             (2, ''A''),
#             (2, ''B''),
#             (3, ''A''),
#             (3, ''B'')],
#            )
```

Comment: Darn it, I swear I thought I tried that, and it didn't work. But it works now! I must have entered it in not the exact form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> *it seems that there should be a simple and easy way to convert one
> level of the multiindex..*

Unfortunately, not yet (*see [pandas/issues/54523](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54523)*).

A workaround would be to convert the header [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) it with [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) :

```
from ast import literal_eval

conv_mux = df.columns.to_frame().map(literal_eval).convert_dtypes()

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(conv_mux) # ---------^ is optional
```

Output :

```
>>> df.columns

MultiIndex([(1, 'A'),
            (1, 'B'),
            (2, 'A'),
            (2, 'B'),
            (3, 'A')],
           names=[0, 1])

>>> df.columns.dtypes.to_dict()

{0: Int64Dtype(), 1: string[python]}
```

Used input :

```
op = """,1,1,2,2,3
,'A','B','A','B','A'
0,1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5"""

from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(op) ,header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

Comment: One solution I found is to convert to DataFrame and back: `dfidx = df.columns.to_frame(index=False);dfidx['levelname'] = dfidx['levelname'].astype('int64');df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfidx)

Comment: That would be an option too. See that you can pass a `dict` to [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) : `dfidx.astype({0: "int", 1: "string"})` but that won't get rid of the single quotes level 1. You'll still have `'A'` instead of `A`.

Comment: But we can do : `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(op.replace("'", "")), header=[0, 1], index_col=0); dfidx = df.columns.to_frame(index=False).astype({0: "int"});df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfidx)`.